# Laravel: get single model with a relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have `Ability` and `Hero` models. The relation is many to many.

When I return collection I am able to use `Hero::with('Abilities')->get()`

Is there a way to achieve this with a single model (e.g. `$hero->with('Abilities')->get()`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That will load a relation for a given model object:

```
$hero->load('Abilities');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$hero->with('Abilities')->get();` won't load the relation on the hero model, using `Hero::where('id', $id)->with('abilities')->first();` will load it but `$hero->load('Abilities');` is the best solution in my opinion